# como puedo crear una grilla a partir de un bucle while

Tags: php, while, condiciones, bucles

Necesito crear una grilla de 8 elementos con el nombre de los artículos, la cantidad y el precio con números aleatorios, llevo esto hecho, pero no sé cómo usar el bucle while para formar la grilla.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Nombre</td><td>Cantidad</td><td>Precio</td></tr>

<?php
$a = 0
while($a<=8){
echo "<tr>
         <td>Nombre".$a."</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>".(rand(1,100))."</td>
      </tr>";
      a = ++;
}
?>
```

El bucle tiene que ser si o si un while no me permite usar for.

Comment: Tu error es simple, solo cambia `a = ++;` por solo `$a++;`

Answer (score 0):

Comentarios respecto tu código:

1. en la línea donde declaras la variable **$a** te hacía falta colocar el punto y coma
2. Una de las formas de hacer el incremento de uno mas uno es **$a++** y tu lo tenías como **$a = ++** lo cual es una sintáxis incorrecta

Por lo tanto para que se genere tu tabla con valores aleatorios tu propio código quedaría así

```
<?php
$a = 0;
while($a<=8){
echo "<tr>
         <td>Nombre".$a."</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>".(rand(1,100))."</td>
      </tr>";
$a++;
}
```

Ahora bien para agregar las etiquetas de  que abre y  que cierra pudiera ser de este modo:

```
<?php
$a = 0;
echo "<table> <tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Precio</th></tr>";
while($a<=8){
echo "<tr>
         <td>Nombre".$a."</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>".(rand(1,100))."</td>
      </tr>";
$a++;
}
echo "</table>";
```